# Sankey Plot Help For Survey Data

Tags: r, ggplot2, survey, sankey-diagram, geom

i have some survey data that i wanted to visualize and attempted to use a sankey plot to do so. the data has alot text in the form of enter your own response under categories as shown in the picture. i was wondering how would i adjust the plot so that i could read these entries as they are cut off. as well as the possibility of grouping these end nodes or differentiating the color of the lines based on their categories. Open to all suggestions here. here is my code

```
pl <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x
                     , next_x = next_x
                     , node = node
                     , next_node = next_node
                     , fill = factor(x)
                     , label = node))

pl <- pl + geom_sankey(flow.alpha = 0.5
                       , node.color = "black"
                       , show.legend = FALSE)

pl <- pl + geom_sankey_label(size = 3, color = "black", fill = "white", hjust = 0, vjust = .5)
```

[image: My Sankey Plot]